# Swap multiple images from javascript array

Tags: javascript, image

I am coding a website with multiple pages of thumbnail image galleries. I want to populate the thumbnail images on each page from an array, so that I won't have to change the path of multiple images on each page. The folder path is defined in a var statement - which I would like to be the only unique element on each gallery page - and the images in each gallery's folder will have the same names (t1.jpg, t2.jpg, etc.).

I have the main image swap working, and tried to use a similar function for the thumbnails, but it doesn't work because the image ID is the same for all the thumbnail images. I could give each image a unique ID, but then would have to call a separate function for each thumbnail swap (15 per page).

I am a javascript novice and despite much searching I can't figure out how to work around this or find any similar examples. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

// Thumbnail Image Array
var imgThumbs = new Array (
"t1.jpg",
"t2.jpg",
"t3.jpg"
)

//Main Image Array
var imgArray = new Array (
"f1.jpg",
"f2.jpg",
"f3.jpg"
)

//Image Path
var imgPath = "images/portfolio/samples/";

function preloadImages() {
     for(var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
          var tmpImg = new Image;
          tmpImg.src = imgPath + imgArray[i];
     }
}

//Thumbnail Image Swap Function
function loadThumb(thumbID) {
     var theThumb = document.getElementById('theThumb');
     var newThumb;
     newThumb = imgThumbs[thumbID];
     theThumb.src = imgPath + newThumb;
}

//Main Image Swap Function
function swapImage(imgID) {
     var theImage = document.getElementById('theImage');
     var newImg;
     newImg = imgArray[imgID];
     theImage.src = imgPath + newImg;
}


//-->
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="portfolio">
  <div id="thumbnails">
    <a href="#" class="dimmer" onclick="swapImage(0)"><img src="images/portfolio/noThumb.jpg" id="theThumb" onload="loadThumb(0)"  alt="Architect Portfolio Thumbnail 1" width="75" height="75" /></a>
    <a href="#" class="dimmer" onclick="swapImage(1)"><img src="images/portfolio/noThumb.jpg" id="theThumb" onload="loadThumb(1)" alt="Architect Portfolio Thumbnail 2" width="75" height="75" /></a>
    <a href="#" class="dimmer" onclick="swapImage(2)"><img src="images/portfolio/noThumb.jpg" id="theThumb" onload="loadThumb(2)" alt="Architect Portfolio Thumbnail 3" width="75" height="75" /></a>
  </div>
  <div id="mainImage"><img src="images/portfolio/samples/f1.jpg" alt="Architecture Portfolio Main Image" id="theImage" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each ID attribute on the page should be unique. Remove them and rewrite your code as:

```
function loadThumb(thumbID, obj) {
     var newThumb = imgThumbs[thumbID];
     obj.src = imgPath + newThumb;
}
```

And the corresponding HTML part will look like

```
<img src="images/portfolio/noThumb.jpg" onload="loadThumb(0, this)"  
    alt="Architect Portfolio Thumbnail" width="75" height="75" />
```

ps: Actually I do not see the purpose of that script - `onload` function could be triggered before the image is loaded in a `preloadImages()` function.

pps: try this code http://jsfiddle.net/4cKvs/  and jQuery variant http://jsfiddle.net/zSBNR/

Comment: Cheery, that works great Thanks! I don't understand your ps: though... is there a cleaner way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: @Jason the 'noThumb.jpg' could load faster than image preload in `preloadImages()`. Oh, I see that you do not preload the thumbs, so why not to write them directly in img tag? you could even generate the list of 'a' and 'img' tags with javascript.

Comment: Cheery, I'm sure you could do those things. I am only a beginner.  One question: Not all of the thumbnail galleries have a full set of images. Is there a simple way to execute the swap only if there is an image to pass?

Comment: @Jason `Is there a simple way to bypass the function if there is no image to pass` Do you mean that thumb image may not exists on the server?

Comment: Exactly. There are 15 possible thumbnails, but some sets have fewer.

Comment: @Jason Do you want to show noThumb.jpg for non-existing files or just not to show them at all?

Comment: I would like to show noThumb.jpg if there is no thumbnail image.

Comment: @Jason and one more question - do you have a few images and a set of thumbs for each of them or just one image with a set of the thumbs? Just trying to understand why do you need `var imgArray`

Comment: Each thumb corresponds to a large image which is swapped by the swapImage function - from the var imgArray. OH, I just realized that even if the thumbnail image is absent I don't have a method for disabling the swapImage function for that thumb. Ugh.

Comment: @Jason You did not answer on the question - do you have only one place for images with `id="theImage"`?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. There is only one main image (theImage). Here is my page in progress if it is useful to see: http://revealdev.com/gdwa/gallery_test.php

Comment: @Jason Try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/gAQp5/ With jQuery it is much easier to perform.

Comment: Cheery, thank you so much! Your jQuery script is loading the image thumbnails as expected. I hesitate to ask for more, and I don't understand much of your script, but it looks as if you intended it to disable the onclick event for absent images which doesn't seem to be working. If you are willing to take a look, the revised page is up revealdev.com/gdwa/gallery_test.php

Comment: @Jason it does not use jQuery, just a pure javascript. I meant that with jQuery it will be much shorter. As of onclick, modify it as `obj.onclick = function() {return false;};` jQuery is interesting only if you are going to use it not only on one page.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to have fixed it.

Comment: @Jason ok, than try the 'full power' as `obj.onclick = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();};` if you want - it is possible to remove the `a` tag around the image in that case. I just tried to write the code as simple as possible.

Comment: That works great! I need the 'a' tag because there is a ':hover' selector which is a highlight effect (it changes the images from 50% opacity to 100%). Is it possible to remove this class from absent thumbnails along with the 'onerror' function? I tried adding 'obj.removeAttribute('class');' but it doesn't work.

Comment: `obj.className = '';` but it will remove all classes. Read this http://www.openjs.com/scripts/dom/class_manipulation.php and with jQuery it is much easier http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Comment: Thanks for the links. I tried `obj.className = '';` to test, but I think it isn't working because the class is applied to the `a` tag rather than `img`. Would a separate function be required to change the `a` class?

Comment: @Jason `obj.parentNode.className = '';`

Comment: Super, thanks! One last question: `obj.onclick = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();};` is returning the error "'preventDefault' is null or not an object" in IE7 & IE8 (works fine in Safari, Firefox, Chrome). I looked around for an answer and came up with `obj.onclick = function(e) { if (e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); } else { e.returnValue = false; }; e.stopPropagation();};` which was suggested in another thread, but it still returns the error in IE. Any ideas?

Comment: `but it still returns the error in IE` which one? it should not call `preventDefault` in that case.

Comment: "'preventDefault' is null or not an object"  Debugger highlights `if (e.preventDefault)`

Comment: Ok, I see that I wrote a little bit more in my previous example than there should be. Look at this one http://jsfiddle.net/4cKvs/  it 'remembers' if image was not found and does not swap images in that case. It also gets the index of the array from the id value of the element. ps: I have to go to the gym for a couple of hours.

Comment: Yes! That worked. I will study it and try to understand what is going on. Cheery I can't thank you enough for your time and patience. Have a wonderful weekend!

Comment: @Jason and this is how it can be done with jQuery - much more readable http://jsfiddle.net/zSBNR/

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Javascript novice I recommend you to search in google about
jQuery it is can help you a lot (Google also using it).