# Javascript Automatic Image Swap w/ Multiple Arrays

Tags: javascript, rotation

I'm currently working on an image rotator. The rotation part is complete, however I'm expanding the functionality based on a need that I've found.

**Goal:** Rotate through a preset list of slides that contain hardcoded images, however on each subsequent rotation, use js to swap to a new image for specific slides that require a variation.

The script below works fine, but I feel like it's not the most efficient way to go about this. Currently I'm tackling it by running a new loop and function for each of the specific slides that I've chosen to be the "different" ones. My guess is there is a way to do it using one function and loop, but I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

**Anology:** Let's say I have an image rotator that displays a list of cars and every 5 seconds it rotates to the next slide. Each slide is designated for a different model of car, however for some models, I want to display a different variation of that model on each iteration of the entire rotator.

**Example:**

Here is a list of how each pass of the rotator would print.

```
- Ford Focus
- Toyota Celica
- Hyundai Elantra
- Dodge Ram
- Motorcycle

- Ford Focus
- Toyota Celica GTS
- Hyundai Elantra
- Dodge Ram w/ additional accessories
- Motorcycle

- Ford Focus
- Toyota Celica w/ Spoiler
- Hyundai Elantra
- Dodge Ram different color
- Motorcycle
```

Here is my current script:

```html
<script>
window.onload=function() {
    imgCont = document.getElementById('example1');
    c_imgCont = document.getElementById('example2');
}

var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1; 
     if (typeof(imgCont) != 'undefined' && imgCont != null)
  {
   swapImage(); 
  }

  if (typeof(c_imgCont) != 'undefined' && c_imgCont != null)
  {
   swapImageExample2();
  }

    }
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, x[myIndex-1].dataset.timing);
}


    
var picPaths = ['image1.png','img2.png','img3.png','img4.png'];
var curPic = -1;
//preload the images for smooth animation
var imgO = new Array();
for(i=0; i < picPaths.length; i++) {
    imgO[i] = new Image();
    imgO[i].src = picPaths[i];
}

function swapImage() {
    curPic = (++curPic > picPaths.length-1)? 0 : curPic;
    imgCont.src = imgO[curPic].src;
}

var c_picPaths = ['otherimg1.png','otherimg2.png'];
var c_curPic = -1;
//preload the images for smooth animation
var c_imgO = new Array();
for(l=0; l < c_picPaths.length; l++) {
    c_imgO[l] = new Image();
    c_imgO[l].src = c_picPaths[l];
}

function swapImageExample2() {
    c_curPic = (++c_curPic > c_picPaths.length-1)? 0 : c_curPic;
    c_imgCont.src = c_imgO[c_curPic].src;
}


</script>
```

Comment: Careful with terminology - [image rotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794310/rotate-image-with-javascript) vs [image swapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424759/swap-multiple-images-from-javascript-array)

Comment: Apologies, in my industry this specific product is referred to as a rotator (as it rotates through slides automatically). Definitely need to be careful with that!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just adjust your data structure so that any "image" in the `picPaths` array can be an array of image paths. Then use a function to get the image path to show. See simple example below.

Notice the structure of `picPaths`. Also notice that the 2nd and 4th images in the rotation (transport, nature) rotate through different images each iteration of the `picPaths` array.

```html
<img id="example1" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats/1/"/>


<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        imgCont = document.getElementById('example1');
        swapImage();
    }

    var picPaths = [
            "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats/1/",
            [
                "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/transport/1/",
                "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/transport/2/",
                "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/transport/3/",
                "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/transport/4/"
            ],
            "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/1/",
            [
                "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/1/",
                "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/2/",
                "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/3/",
                "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/4/",
                "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/5/"
            ],
            "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/"
        ],
        curImg = 0;

    function getImagePath(path) {
        if(Array.isArray(path)) {
            var temp = path.shift();
            path.push(temp);
            return temp;
        }
        else {
            return path;
        }
    }

    function swapImage() {
        curImg = curImg < (picPaths.length - 1) ? curImg : 0;        
        var imgPath = getImagePath(picPaths[curImg]);
        console.clear();
        console.log('current index in picPaths:', curImg, 'current image path to display:', imgPath);
        imgCont.src = imgPath;
        curImg++;
        setTimeout(function() {
            swapImage();
        }, 4000);
    }
</script>
```

Based on your comment I made a 2nd example. I think this is what you mean.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    carousel(picPaths, 'slide');
};

var picPaths = [
        "https://placeimg.com/640/480/any/sepia/1",
        [
            "https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech/1",
            "https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech/2",
            "https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech/3",
            "https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech/4"
        ],
        "https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals/1",
        [
            "https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature/1",
            "https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature/2",
            "https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature/3",
            "https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature/4",
            "https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature/5"
        ],
        "https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch/1"
    ];

function carousel(imgPaths, imgClass) {
    var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName(imgClass);

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(imgs, function(imgElem, idx) {
        var timing = imgElem.dataset.timing,
            path = imgPaths[idx];

        swapImage(imgElem, path, timing);
    });

    function getImagePath(path) {
        if(Array.isArray(path)) {
            var temp = path.shift();
            path.push(temp);
            return temp;
        }
        else {
            return path;
        }
    };

    function swapImage(imgElem, path, timing) {
        var imgPath = getImagePath(path);

        imgElem.src = imgPath;
        setTimeout(function() {
            swapImage(imgElem, path, timing);
        }, timing);
    };
}
```

```css
.slide {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="slide_1" class="slide" src="" data-timing="8000">
  <img id="slide_2" class="slide" src="" data-timing="4000">
  <img id="slide_3" class="slide" src="" data-timing="10000">
  <img id="slide_3" class="slide" src="" data-timing="6000">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I see exactly what you're saying here! The only issue that I see is that it uses a set timeout duration. How can I make that dynamic for each slide?

Just to provide an example of what I do now:

    `<img id="slide_1" class="slide" src="example1.png"  data-timing="8000">  
    <img id="slide_2" class="slide" src="example2.png"  data-timing="4000">  
    <img id="slide_3" class="slide" src="example3.png"  data-timing="10000">` 

Data-timing is the timeout value for each slide.

Comment: Added a 2nd example of what I think you wanted.